# Label and alignment with circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In the following circuit drawn with [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz), how can the ground and antenna vertical lines be aligned (that is, draw in the same abscissa)?

Also, how to fix the labeling of the ground and antenna components, so that the labels stays at the left of the component?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw
    (0,0.8) node [ground] (A) {}
    to [short] (0,1)
    to [short] (6,1)
    to [R=$R$,v>=$V_R$] (6,4)
    to [C=$C$] (3,4)
    to [L=$L$] (1,4) node [antenna,xscale=-1,] (B) {}
    (0,1) to [open,v>=$V_0$] (0,4)
    (A) -- node [anchor=east] {Terra} (A)
    (B) -- node [anchor=east] {Antena} (B)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw
    (0,0.8) node [ground] (A) {} node [anchor=east] {Terra}
    to [short] (0,1)
    to [short] (6,1)
    to [R=$R$,v>=$V_R$] (6,4)
    to [C=$C$] (3,4)
    to [L=$L$] (1,4) node [antenna,xscale=-.7,] (B) {} node [left=3em,above=2em,anchor=east] {Antena}
    (0,1) to [open,v>=$V_0$] (0,4)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the alignment of the ground and the antenna in the same vertical line has been done visually, by trial and error. It would be better if it could be done by programming, using anchors, for instance.